# iterate through alphabet in prolog

Tags: prolog

Let's say I want to have some rule for comparison similar to

```
isin(0,_).
isin(N,List) :- member(N,List), write(N), N1 is N-1, isin(N1,List).
```

but the List will contain alphabet symbols (e.g. [a,b,d,e,h]). How can I send the next element to the iteration? (so N is a symbol, not a number). And if it's not possible, how can I make something similar?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@julkiewicz is almost there:

```
isin(a, _).
isin(Char, List) :-
    member(Char, List),
    char_code(Char, Code),
    write(Char),
    Code1 is Code-1,
    char_code(Char1, Code1),
    isin(Char1, List).
```

Note that the predicate will always succeed on `a`, just like your original version always succeeds on `0`. You can prevent that by changing the base clause to something like

```
isin(Char, _) :-
    char_code(a, A),
    Char is A-1.
```

(But this is really an ugly hack.)

Comment: Thanks! it worked perfectly! (but apparently it doesn't solved my problem xD)

Comment: @Kirby: I suspected as much, as I didn't understand your code in the first place... maybe you could post a new question describing what problem you were trying to solve?

Answer (score 2):

NOTE: This works on strings, not on symbols as requested by the OP.

Well it seems like characters are interpreted as number lists really. So this works:

```
?- X = "a".
X = [97].
?- X is "a".
X = 97.
?- X is "a" + 1.
X = 98.
```

So this is what I'd propose:

```
isin("a", _).
isin(N, List) :- member(N, List), N1 is N - 1, isin([N1], List).
```

Haven't written anything in this language for a long time though.

Comment: Except that `write` on the string (list of char codes) `"a"` prints `[97]`.

Comment: Yea, right. They are list numbers, but `is` automatically unpacks them.

Comment: problem is, the a is a symbol, not a string (they're in graph vertex, like graph(a,b).)

Comment: Ok, got it. So you actually want to work on symbols. I remember now this distinction. This won't help you then.